# How does this while loop work?

Tags: python, while-loop, deque

Hoping someone can explain what's going on with this while loop.

```
x=deque([(1,2,3)])
while x:
    a,b,c = x.popleft()
    do stuff with values in x
    x.append((d,e,f))
```

I get that `x` is a `deque` with 3 items which are constantly being replaced by new values.  But I've never encountered a `while` loop without some kind of condition.  How will the loop know when to stop?

Comment: everything in python has it boolean value. So do `deques`. They return `False` when empty. Thats your exit condition. Having said that, there are such loops (at least sort of) that look like this: `while True:`. These loops can only be terminated from the inside using `break`!

Comment: Also note that your deque has not three, but just one element (being a tuple of three), and the loop will probably never stop, as `x` can never be empty with that `x.append` at the end (unless there is a `break` or `continue` in the omitted code)

Comment: Also note that the loop is *infinite* for the reasons stated in @ Hettinger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58679920/355230)

Answer (score 1):

```
x=deque([(1,2,3)]) # create new deque
while x: # while not empty
    a,b,c = x.popleft() # pop values and assign them to a and b and c
    # do stuff with values in x - this is comment too
    x.append((d,e,f)) # assumes produced new values d 
                      #and e and f and pushes them to x
# this assumes there is always d and e and f values and stays forever in loop
```

as explained in [How to check if a deque is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652278/how-to-check-if-a-deque-is-empty)

Comment: the `do stuff with values in x` is probably where the `d`, `e` and `f` come from. So it is not exactly a comment but rather pseudocode. That is my undertanding at least

Answer (score 1):

As written, the code is an infinite loop because it adds data at the same rate as it is being removed.

If the size was being whittled down, the `while x` would terminate the loop when the deque was empty.